# Does imap.fetch(uid,'RFC822')[0].attr['RFC822'] return the entire message, including attachments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, imap

Wondering if there's a way I can avoid fetching the attachments as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it returns the entire email source. The attachments are encoded as email parts.

You can use the [Ruby Mail library](http://github.com/mikel/mail) to extracts all the attachments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about ruby , but it can be done only fetching Email Header.
I am Fetching Email header in Python like below:

```
    resp, data = obj.uid('FETCH' , ','.join(map(str,uid_lst)),'(RFC822.HEADER RFC822.SIZE)')
```

where uid_lst is the list of uids of emails which you want to fetch.

Note: Email which has value of header field Content-Type = 'Multipart-Mixed' has an attachment.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do, is download the email body(ies), there isn't a clean way of doing this (at least none that I disovered).

What I had to do, was first download the headers and the body structures. Once I had the headers, I could determine what type of email it was (multi-part, alternative, or just a single bodied email).

Once I knew the structure, I could download the plain text or html body part as a body section.

Does that help?
--Dave